# Is 'phone wrong?

Tags: orthography

I have seen *phone* spelled as *'phone*. Obviously this is an acknowledgement that the full word used to be *telephone*. Is this spelling objectionable?

Comment: Language evolves.  Radar, laser, and scuba used to be acronyms, now they are words.  Phone used to be an abbreviation, now it's a word.

Comment: @Rathony: Why? Perhaps because the meaning ***phone** = A speech sound; the smallest unit of sound in speech that can be distinguished from any other such unit* (OED's first definition, citation 1866) ***predates*** the invention (or at least, the *naming*) of the telephone (which I'd be inclined to fix at [1876](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invention_of_the_telephone), when various inventors were slugging it out to see who could get their implementation patented first).

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP needs to specify the context. Not me. Also, I agree that the word *phone* might have been used first, but why would you spell it that way? That was my question.

Comment: @Rathony: I don't really follow you there. As it happens, OED's first citation for ***phone** = telephone* is 1880. That and the next one (1883) don't have an apostrophe,for which orthography OED's first citation isn't until 1886. I don't really suppose "disambiguation" is a significant factor; it's presumably about whether the speaker/writer accepts the shorter form as a word "in its own right" (as opposed to being a slangy colloquial abbreviation).

Comment: @Rathony: The apostrophised version was never actually *dominant*, but [in the early decades](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%27phone%2Cphone&year_start=1900&year_end=1935&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%27%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cphone%3B%2Cc0) it was quite common, accounting for about 1 in 3 of all instances of the abbreviated form. The abbreviated form became established very early, but even in those early decades, both the short forms combined amounted to less than a tenth of usages of the full form ***telephone***.

Comment: I used to see ***'phone*** fairly often when I was much younger, but I don't recall seeing that presentation in years.  I would say that it's now an anachronism, at the very least.

Comment: (When I was in grade school the holiday at the end of October was universally spelled "Hallowe'en", and anyone leaving out the `'` in their written work would get marked down.  Now you hardly ever see it spelled any way other than "Halloween".  Things change over time.)

Comment: Depending on context, the apostrophe before _phone_ might stand for _tele_, _micro_, _gramo_, _xylo_, or some other prefix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming you are referring to the apostrophe that precedes the word phone as being the issue here. In this case, it is quite unnecessary as "phone" itself is a word. I have never seen the apostrophe before, and it would actually cause confusion as opposed to clarity to use this form.

According to the University of Sussex, this form is outdated.

> Such clipped forms are not regarded as contractions, and they should not be written with apostrophes. Writing things like hippo', bra', 'cello and 'phone will, not to mince words, make you look like an affected old fuddy duddy who doesn't quite approve of anything that's happened since 1912.

[University of Sussex](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/contractions)

Comment: Except that's written by Larry Trask (who should be credited, rather than the university). He had some oddball ideas.

Comment: As he was a professor at that university, and the university specifically states that they maintain this grammar guide, I don't see how citing it as the University of Sussex is wrong. If the "New York Times" published something, I would be correct in citing that newspaper as the source, and not just specifically the author. And attacking the author on his other ideas does not make this information any less true. I'm not sure what you were getting at with your post.

Comment: I see **'cello** from time to time (as you say, usually from "affected old fuddy duddies"), but I don't think I've ever seen **bra'**. Now that really *would* be an extreme affectation from my perspective.

Comment: @trident No, it explicitly states *The document you are looking at is a textbook*, with the copyright explicitly retained by Larry Trask— he is not writing on behalf of the university. He is more like a columnist appearing in the New York Times than a staff reporter.

Comment: @choster has ably explained the attribution. The rest of my comment was intended to imply that **anything** Larry Trask wrote should be taken with a bushel of salt.

Comment: "Affected old fuddy duddy", that's brilliant. Thanks